# Mouslistener causing problems

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener

I've have created a GoInvisible class in my code which implements a mouse listener, i'm tryna use the mouse pressed and the mouse released methods to get my frame to go transparent and then return to normal on the press and release of a button on the frame. i'm invoking these methods in an inner class which implements an action listener that handles button events but then for some reason when i run the app the the frame never shows up.

Here's the frame code;

```
public class FNAFrame extends JFrame {

public FNAFrame()
{
    super ("FNA Comments Generator");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    setResizable(false);
    TextFrame comps = new TextFrame();
    add(comps);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                // 
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


            new FNAFrame();

        }
    });
  }  
} // end of class FNA Frame
```

Here is the components class;

```
public class TextFrame extends JPanel 
{
    private JButton Go_Shadow;

public TextFrame()
{
    super(new GridBagLayout());

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
    setBackground(Color.white);

    init();  
   } // end of class constructor

    private void init()
    { 
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);

        // button to display date in textarea
        Go_Shadow = new JButton("Shadow");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(Go_Shadow, gbc);


        // adding listeners to components
        // registering all components with their respective listeners
        CompHandler compHandler = new CompHandler();
        Go_Shadow.addActionListener(compHandler);
    }

    // class to handle text fields
    private class CompHandler implements ActionListener
    {    
        private MouseEvent me;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
        {
            Object button_command = e.getActionCommand();



                if (button_command.equals("Go_Shadow"))
                { 
                    GoInvisible invisy = new GoInvisible();

                    invisy.mousePressed(me);
                    invisy.mouseReleased(me);    
                }

        }
    } // end component handler class 
} // end of TextFrame class
```

Here is the mouse listener class

```
 public class GoInvisible implements MouseListener {


 FNAFrame Parentpane = new FNAFrame();
 TextFrame compPanel = new TextFrame();


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    Parentpane.setUndecorated(true);
    Parentpane.setOpacity(0.5f);
    compPanel.setOpaque(true);
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    Parentpane.setUndecorated(false);
    compPanel.setOpaque(true);
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}   
}
```

Comment: Do you think that `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` might be problem...?

Comment: Also... you never add a MouseListener or MouseMotionListener to *anything*. i.e., where do you have `addMouseListener(...)` anywhere?

Comment: Are you adding the MouseListener to some of your classes ?

Comment: [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a series of issues...

1. You need to get rid of `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` from your methods, these will cause problems and stop your code from executing
2. The `actionCommand` of your button is not `"Go_Shadow"`, it will be the text of the button, unless you specify it otherwise.
3. You shouldn't be adding a using a `MouseListener` or `ActionListener`, but instead should be monitoring the state of the `ButtonModel`
4. You are creating new instances of `FNAFrame` and `TextFrame` in your `GoInvisible` handler, which have no relationship to those instances which are actually on the screen!

Instead, you should monitor the state of the `ButtonModel`, for example...

```
Go_Shadow.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
        JFrame window = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(TextFrame.this);
        if (model.isArmed() && model.isPressed()) {
            window.setUndecorated(true);
            window.setOpacity(0.5f);
            setOpaque(false);
        } else if (model.isArmed() && !model.isPressed()) {
            setOpaque(true);
            window.setOpacity(1f);
            window.setUndecorated(false);
        }
    }
});
```

But, you will still find that this causes issues, as the state of the frame's border, can't be changed once it's displayed

A better solution might be to use a `JToggleButton`, for example

```
public class TextFrame extends JPanel {

    private JToggleButton Go_Shadow;

    public TextFrame() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        setBackground(Color.white);

        init();
    } // end of class constructor

    private void init() {
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        // button to display date in textarea
        Go_Shadow = new JToggleButton("Shadow");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(Go_Shadow, gbc);

        // adding listeners to components
        // registering all components with their respective listeners
        Go_Shadow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame window = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(TextFrame.this);
                Point location = window.getLocation();
                if (Go_Shadow.isSelected()) {
                    window.dispose();
                    window.setUndecorated(true);
                    window.setOpacity(0.5f);
                    setOpaque(false);
                } else {
                    window.dispose();
                    window.setOpacity(1f);
                    window.setUndecorated(false);
                    setOpaque(true);
                }
                window.setLocation(location);
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

} // end of TextFrame class
```

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: thanks much madpro.. can't try it now gotta go to work but it definitely looks promising

Comment: so i tried it in my test software it works perfect but when i plug it into my software the frame doesn't show up and it spits out null pointer errors..
these null pointer errors points to the line:
-> Go_Shadow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { and 
-> Point Location = window.getLocation();

Comment: Without a working example, I would guess the component you are passing `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor` isn't attached to any windows

Comment: ok so i got it to work, when i switch the anonymous class to a lambda expression.. but now it goes transparent  but when clicking the toggle button it to reappear it throws an error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is not opaque
 at java.awt.Frame.setUndecorated(Frame.java:927)
 at fna.comments.generator.FnaComponents.lambda$init$0(FnaComponents.java:257)
 at fna.comments.generator.FnaComponents$$Lambda$90/1820110257.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)

Comment: ok i found the error.. in the else condition i had the setUndecorated statement before the setOpacity statement.. so it throwed an error now everything is cool.. thanks much madpro

Comment: You don't seem to have set the window to been opaque before redecorating it ... I guess